# Alter tables with lobos migrations

Tags: clojure, compojure

Anybody knows how to alter table (add column) with lobos migrations?
There is no documentation on this that I can find -- any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Lobos will run all migrations pending according to the `lobos_migrations` table on your database.

The syntax for modifying an existent table is using `alter`, you can find some docs [here](http://budu.github.io/lobos/documentation.html).

For adding a new column this is an example migration:

```
(defmigration add-column-test 
   (up []
       (alter :add (table :your_table (integer :test_column))))
   (down []))
```

You can also find other `alter` options such as column rename in the [tests source code](https://github.com/budu/lobos/blob/master/test/lobos/test/migration.clj#L34)